# Correct path for pik, ruby libraries and git bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git-bash, pik

In order to push my local SQLite3 database to Heroku, I have installed pik so that I can use ruby -v 192. (I was getting a timezone error, and other posts suggested that it may be due to using ruby version 193).

I followed the directions on github:
http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.com/book/ch02-03.html

I am now able to switch between v 193 and v192, and have bundle installed the necessary gems I'm aware of, including pg (0.12.2 x86-mingw32) and taps (0.3.24).

Everything is fine when I'm in v193.

However, in v192, when I try to run:

```
Heroku run rake db:migrate
```

or

```
Heroku db:push
```

...I get an error page that reads:

```
Running 'rake db:migrate' attached to terminal... up, run.1
bash: bin/bundle: c:/Users/umezo/.pik/rubies/Ruby-192-p290/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

This seems like a path problem, as my Ruby libraries are in c:/, and not c:/Users/Umezo/.pik.  I think I may have installed the initial path to v192 in the .pik folder instead of in c:/.  What can I do to fix this problem?

My relevant files are saved as recommended in the github instructions:

```
c:/Ruby192
c:/Ruby193
c:/tools/pik.bat
c:/tools/pik.ps1
c:/tools/pik_runner.exe
c:/Users/umezo/.bashrc
c:/Users/umezo/.pik/.pikrc
c:/Users/umezo/.pik/config.yml
```

respectively, and the file contents are:

.pikrc

```
#!/bin/sh
pik_path=/c/tools
function pik  {
  $pik_path/pik_runner.exe pik.sh $@
  [[ -s $USERPROFILE/.pik/pik.sh ]] && source $USERPROFILE/.pik/pik.sh
  unset GEM_HOME
  unset GEM_PATH
}
```

config.yml

```
--- 
"192: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]": 
  :path: !ruby/object:Pathname 
    path: C:/Ruby192/bin

"193: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]": 
  :path: !ruby/object:Pathname 
    path: C:/Ruby193/bin
--- {}
```

.bashrc

```
[[ -s $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc ]] && source $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc
unset GEM_HOME
unset GEM_PATH
```

I'm still not sure how all of these files are interconnected, or what exactly each of them does, so am not sure which files to change or move.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: `heorku run` runs a process remotly on the heroku platform. The heroku platform runs on linux not windows.

Comment: Thanks Will. Why do you think "heroku run rake db:migrate" gives me the error message with "no interpreter"? Heroku logs shows "Error: No such file or directory - bundle exec rails server." A local "rake db:migrate" completes with no problem (that I can tell). Also, I can successfully connect to the local server by directly entering "bundle exec rails server"

Comment: Do other `heroku` commands work? like `heroku help`

Comment: Hi Azolo. Yes, heroku help gives me the list of commands/topics

Comment: I think `pik` is trying to capture the bash runner that `heroku` is trying to run ruby in, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It seems that pik (or heroku?) is trying to run a ruby installation at $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc/Ruby192, while I'm trying to set up a path through c:/Ruby192. My initial installation placed Ruby192 in the .pikrc folder, but I moved it out to C:/ because that's where my Ruby193 folder is. Do I need to move my Ruby192 folder back into the .pikrc folder? Or is there a way I can fix the path to point to c:/Ruby192?

Comment: If you moved **before** you installed `bundler` then I might be wrong. But try reinstalling your `gems`, in particular `bundler`.

Comment: @Azolo: Thanks for your help. I ended up unable to push this app. However, I built a second app, and was able to push it to Heroku by switching to ruby -v1.9.2 (pik192) and installing the taps gem. It may have been an issue with order of installment, as you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out the root cause of this issue, so ended up reinstalling my ruby installations. Now it works fine!